# How to restrict subfolders of a folder that are showed in sidebar in Sublime Text 2/3?

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

I am able to select folders I would like to work on using different paths inside of the `folders` array in Projects settings. But what if I need only few folders from the folder `templates`? And I don't want to see others. How to perform this restriction?

Now have something like this:

```js
"folders":
[
    {
        "path": "templates"
    },
    {
        "path": "js"
    }
]
```

In `templates` folder, for example, exist folder `users`. And I need restrict directories that should be show from there.
`folder_exclude_patterns: ['users/one', 'users/two']` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the folders' names you don't want to see under folder_exclude_pattern option.

```
"folders":
[
    {
        "path": "templates",
        "folder_exclude_patterns": [
            "i_dont_want_this_folder",
            "and this folder",
            "i_want_this/but not this"
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "js"
    }
]
```

Comment: Actual problem is with subfolders. For example, if I need only folders `one` and `two` inside of `templates/users`. Slash doesn't work for me... That is why only top level folders is available for exclusion via `folder_exclude_patterns`

Comment: I think you are not doing it right. It works for me

Comment: I've tried again. And it work. Sorry about that.

Comment: Did you find a way to exclude all subfolders of a specific folder?

Comment: Add this to folder_exclude_patterns "specific_folder/*"